# How to load huge array data into snappydata using java?

Tags: java, arrays, bulkinsert, snappydata

I'm using snappydata database, I have array data in a table inserted like this

```
insert into test select 2, array(1,2,5,6,7,9);
```

how to load huge array data into snappydata using java?
I tried this

> PreparedStatement s2 = snappy.prepareStatement("insert into
> APP.test(id,likes
> ) values(?,?,);");
>
> PreparedStatement s2 = snappy.prepareStatement("insert into
> APP.test (select (?),
> array(?) ;");

But these statements don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the JDBCWithComplexTypes.scala class from the examples which explains how to deal with complex datatypes using JDBC client connection.